# ProgressBar in a SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-progressbar, android-search

I want to ask if is there some way, how to accomplish to put ProgressBar in a SearchView widget, like on picture below?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I think that here is a complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143510/put-a-progress-spinner-in-a-searchview

Answer (score 0):

i think you can achieve that by adding a view to the actionbar.The view must compose of a layout with an auto-complete view and a progressbar