# Put a progress spinner in a SearchView?

Tags: android

I'm using a SearchView in my Activity. As the user types, I am performing search requests to a server. I want to indicate that some activity is happening. Is it possible to display a progress spinner within the SearchView?

Otherwise, how are people handling this - do we create a custom actionbar parent layout, and within that embed the SearchView?

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <SearchView />
    <ProgressBar />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create the layout for the progressbar. A XML like this should do the job:

**R.layout.loading_icon**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_progress_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next create two functions. One to show the progress bar on your searchview and other to hide it:

```
public void showProgressBar(SearchView searchView, Context context)
{
    int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    if (searchView.findViewById(id).findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar) != null)
        searchView.findViewById(id).findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar).animate().setDuration(200).alpha(1).start();

    else
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.loading_icon, null);
        ((ViewGroup) searchView.findViewById(id)).addView(v, 1);
    }
}
public void hideProgressBar(SearchView searchView)
{
    int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    if (searchView.findViewById(id).findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar) != null)
        searchView.findViewById(id).findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar).animate().setDuration(200).alpha(0).start();
}
```

Comment: Ok am I right in thinking that this solution relies on the fact that google does not release an update where "search_plate" is changed?

Comment: Yes it does. You can also create your own SearchView by coping the one from google sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is not within the SearchView, but this is by far the simplest method to provide progress indication in the ActionBar found here http://blog.denevell.org/android-progress-spinner.html:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Turn it on
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    // And when you want to turn it off
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

If you really want the progress to appear inside the SearchView, I would assume that you could use a FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout (or atleast as a parent), putting the progress in bottom of the XML (which will place it on top of the SearchView).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom SearchView class that extends android.support.v7.widget.SearchView, you'll need to do this:

```
public void init(Context context){

        EditText searchPlate = (EditText) findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        //searchPlate.setHint("Search");
        mSearchPlateView = findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        mSearchPlateView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
    }
public void showProgressBar(Context context) {

        if (mProgressBar != null) {
            mProgressBar.animate()
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .alpha(1)
                    .start();
        }
        else {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.invest_progress_loading, null);
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar);
            ((ViewGroup) mSearchPlateView).addView(relativeLayout, 1);
        }
    }

    public void hideProgressBar() {

        if(mProgressBar == null)
            return;

        mProgressBar.animate()
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .alpha(0)
                    .start();

    }
```