# Xamarin.Android How to add processbar to search view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want add processbar to search view. But searchPlate return null.

```
public void showProgressBar(SearchView searchView, Activity context)
{
    var id = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    var searchPlate = searchView.FindViewById(id);

    ...
}
```

Please help me

**Updated**
I create search view in menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_item_search"
        android:title="Seach Item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:id/search_plate refers to some background artwork in the SearchView. You cannot replace this with a progress bar. SearchView extends LinearLayout, so anything that can be done with a LinearLayout can be done with a SearchView. However, SearchView is a special purpose View. I would not advise modifying its default behavior. So I suggest adding the ProgressBar to the right hand side of the SearchView and put the ProgressBar in indeterminate mode, which is some spinning wheel.

Comment: I have try to implement http://stackoverflow.com/a/26143787/1268455 on xamarin but searchPlate = null.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the searchPlate in my side with your code:

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
        SearchView sv;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            sv = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView1);
            showProgressBar(sv, this);   
        }

        void showProgressBar(SearchView searchView, Context context)
        {
            int id = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
            View searchPlate = searchView.FindViewById(id);

            if (searchView.FindViewById(id).FindViewById(Resource.Id.progressBar1) != null)
            {
                searchView.FindViewById(id).FindViewById(Resource.Id.progressBar1).Animate().SetDuration(200).Alpha(1).Start();
            }
            else
            {
                View v = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.loading, null);
                ((ViewGroup)searchView.FindViewById(id)).AddView(v, 1);
            }
        }
  }
```

you can refer to my project And find out the core issue.

[Here is the project address](https://github.com/mikexxma/SearchView_With_ProgressBarDemo/tree/master/AndroidTransitionDemo)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for demo. But I create search view using menu.

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh you said you got `search_plate` is null, before that how did you get the searchView object from menu?